# If statements with escape characters in Alpine Linux (ash busybox)

Tags: bash, unix, alpine-linux, busybox, ash

I have simple script to prepare file and it is working as intended. All code is executed at docker image alpine:latest (so ash busybox)

```
echo "credentials \"url.com\" {token = \"${VALUE}\"}" > ~/.terraformrc
```

Later I want to prepare test and I am using if [[ ]] syntax for that.

```
if [[ $(cat ~/.terraformrc) != "credentials \"url.com\" {token =\"VALUE\" }" ]]; then exit 1; fi
```

On Bash test is working but on ash/busybox/alpine I get

```
sh: "url.com": unknown operand
```

Also on ash/busybox/alpine when I do echo all is escaping correctly

```
echo "credentials \"url.com\" {token = \"VALUE\" }"
credentials "url.com" {token = "VALUE" }
```

How should I escape " inside [ ] or [[ ]] ?
Thx for help

Comment: In ash `[[` will not work. And what is `-` doing there in front? Please specify the context. If you are running jenkins, gitlab-ci, github-actions, please specify.

Comment: I am running this on gitlab-ci on alpine:latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[ ]]` is for bash, for ash you should use POSIX `[ ]` instead:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

value=VALUE001

echo "credentials \"url.com\" {token = \"$value\"}" > ~/.terraformrc

if [ "$(cat ~/.terraformrc)" != "credentials \"url.com\" {token =\"VALUE001\" }" ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

BTW, you were doing the escaping correctly but you forgot to double quote `$(cat ~/.terraformrc)`